# Correct way of adding a masking layer to a GRU model using the functional API in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to figure out how to use a [Masking layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/masking/) with the functional API in Keras.

Using the non-functional Keras syntax I can easily create a GRU model that masks away all zero values like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add( tf.keras.layers.Masking( mask_value = 0.0, input_shape = ( nTimeSteps, nVariables ) ) )
model.add( tf.keras.layers.GRU( 32 ) )
model.add( tf.keras.layers.Dense( 10, activation = "softmax" ) )
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate = 0.001 )
model.compile( loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

My attempt at replicating this model using the functional API so far looks like this:

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Masking( mask_value = 0.0, input_shape = ( nTimeSteps, nVariables ) )
x = tf.keras.layers.GRU( 32 )( x )
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense( numberOfOutputs, activation = "softmax" )( x )
model = tf.keras.Model( inputs = x, outputs = z )
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate = 0.001 )
model.compile( loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

However, it does not work – it produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Masking' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What is the correct way of using a masking layer with the functional API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss the `Input` layer in the functional API format. Here a dummy example

```
nsamples = 10
nTimeSteps, nVariables = 6, 4
numberOfOutputs = 2
X = np.random.randint(0,6, (nsamples ,nTimeSteps, nVariables))
y = np.random.randint(0,numberOfOutputs, nsamples)

inp = tf.keras.Input(shape = ( nTimeSteps, nVariables ))
x = tf.keras.layers.Masking( mask_value = 0.0 )(inp)
x = tf.keras.layers.GRU( 32 )( x )
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense( numberOfOutputs, activation = "softmax" )( x )

model = tf.keras.Model( inputs = inp, outputs = z )
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( learning_rate = 0.001 )
model.compile( loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'] )

model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```